# Creating shell script on Desktop and not getting a prompt?

Tags: shell-script

I have created a shell script on Desktop. Whenever I open it , I get a prompt to either run in terminal, display and etc. How to remove this prompt?

Comment: What desktop environment are you using?

Comment: @casey Cinnamon

Answer (score 3):

To run your script without having that dialog appear create a `.desktop` file for it:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=My script
Comment="Whatever you want to see when you hover the mouse over the icon"
Exec=/home/prosper/myscript.pl
Icon=/home/prosper/myicon.gif
Terminal=false
Type=Application
```

Save the file on your `Desktop` folder as `myscript.desktop`, and make it executable:

```
chmod a+x ~/Desktop/myscript.desktop
```

It should now appear using the icon `/home/user/myicon.gif` and you can run it by double clicking.

Comment: Can you suggest a script for testing above mentioned? I am trying some echo script , the result of which I cant see. In windows running a batch file with echo displayed the text in a pop up box. Can this be done in linux?

Comment: @pRoSpEr if you want this to be run in a terminal, change `Terminal=false` to `Terminal=true`. Otherwise, to test it, just change Exec to any graphical application. For example `Exec=/usr/bin/xclock`.